# I'm not able to make Web requests in node

Tags: node.js, http

I am making a simple Http request to the google's homepage but instead of data being logged in the console this error is displayed

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.26.163:80

Also I tried making request to the google's geo location API that too didn't get me any data back.

Here is my code(Google's homepage version)

```
const http = require('http');

let req = http.request('http://www.google.co.uk', function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    response.pipe(process.stdout);
});

req.end();
```

I'm behind a proxy server too , could it be because of the proxy server ?If yes how do I set a proxy server in node.js itself . I've done that for npm already.

Comment: It's probably _everything_ to do with your proxy server as your not declaring such in your request setup - see [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#proxies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `host` and `port` variables that point to the proxy in the `options` passed to `http.request`.

```
   var options = {
      host: "proxypath",
      port: 8080,
      path: "http://www.google.co.uk",
      headers: {
        Host: "http://www.google.co.uk"
      }
    };
    http.request(options, function(response) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      response.pipe(process.stdout);
    });
```

Comment: It worked , thank you very much.  Could you please elaborate a bit on what happened under the hood?